# Display record of 1 column comparing results of 2 column

Tags: sql

I have provided with the table details and what is my expected output:

- User (Id, PersonId, IsBlocked, BlockedReason)
- Person (Id, FirstName, LastName)
- Resume (Id, PersonId, IsActive)

Actual value would be

- IsBlocked (Yes - 1 or No - 0 )
- IsActive (Yes - 1 or No - 0)

I need to know whether the user is Blocked, Active, Inactive. User can be in only 1 among all these 3 status.

For example, if user is blocked, he will not be active - So overall I need only 1 status. How can I write a SQL query for this case?

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.  Please provide sample data and desired results *as a table*.

Comment: Readers here are very keen to encourage new posters to make a reasonable effort themselves, and then to show that effort. We do not think that being a beginner at something is a reasonable defence against not using a search engine. Would you try that now, and let us know what you come up with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case Person is the master table which contains all the people so you should left join the user and resume tables to that and use a case statement to get the status,

```
 SELECT P.ID,P.FirstName,p.LastName,case when T.IsBlocked=1 then 'Blocked'
               when R.IsActive =1 then 'Active'
               else  'Inactive' end as user_status
  FROM  Person P 
  LEFT JOIN User U on P.ID=U.PersonId
  LEFT JOIN Resume R on P.Id=R.PersonId
```

Comment: @Vishal my answer was so early than this answer and you accepted but you again accept this one ignoring my answer any reason?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin both worked equally fine, but stackoverflow is allowing to mark only one as right

Comment: @Vishal in that case who answered 1st must need to consider that one and my answer was 10minutes before of this answer btw if you think you are fair enough then thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE` statement

```
SELECT p.FirstName,p.LastName,
       CASE WHEN t.IsBlocked=1 THEN 'Blocked'
            WHEN r.IsActive =1 THEN 'Active'
            ELSE 'Inactive' END as user_status
FROM User t JOIN Person p ON t.PersonId=p.Id
                     JOIN Resume r ON t.PersonId=r.PersonId
```